# Proving of congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have a question:
[image]

and here's what i tried:

```
Because x≡6(mod 8), we have x = 8k + 6 for some integer k.
Because y≡3(mod 8), we have y = 8l + 3 for some integer l.
```

the problem is with my understanding on how should i perform the substitution in the

$2(x + y)^21 + 3xy$.

would it be like:

$2(8k+6+8l+3)^{21}+ 3(8k+6)(8l+3)$?

Am I doing this right? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are in the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x\equiv6\pmod8$ and since $y\equiv3\pmod8$, $x+y\equiv1\pmod 8$ and $xy\equiv2\pmod 8$, and this last congruence implies that $3xy\equiv6\pmod8$. Therefore, $2(x+y)^{21}+3xy\equiv2+6\pmod8\equiv0\pmod8$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x+y\equiv 1  \pmod 8$ and $xy\equiv18\equiv2\pmod 8.$ Thus, $2(x+y)^{21}+3xy\equiv2+6\equiv0\pmod 8$, which proves the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Let's compute $\pmod{8}$. One has

$$x+y\equiv 6+3\equiv 1\pmod{8}$$

And so $(x+y)^{21}\equiv 1$. Now

$$xy\equiv 6\cdot 3\equiv 2\pmod{8}$$

Adding together we get

$$2(x+y)^{21}+3xy\equiv 2\cdot 1+3\cdot 2\equiv 0\pmod{8}$$